# Convert string 'ddMMMyyyy' to date value in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, datetime-format

I have one column in Hive with below format:

```
25Oct2016  : ddMMMyyyy
```

but when i use below command :

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a,
                                    'ddMMMyyyy'),
                    'yyyy-mm-dd')
  from test_7 limit 10;
```

It brings below answer which is wrong :

```
2016-00-25
```

But it should bring `2016-10-25`

what is the problem??

Answer (score 3):

The correct string pattern would be

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

You are trying to access the minutes with `mm`